# How to export annotations from qpdfview?

Tags: pdf, extract, annotation

I have a pdf with annotations created from [qpdfview](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/qpdfview.1.html) but it seems that the annotations don't show up in other pdf editors. I tried other pdf editors both in linux and MacOS but nothing.

[qpdfview](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/qpdfview.1.html) doesn't have any specific menu saying export annotations or anything similar. I just saved the file and no annotations show up in the other pdf editors. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Which PDF viewers did you tested? On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I see annotations at least in Okular and Atril.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried mpdfeditor & evince, also preview in OSx.